# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.ui::MouseCursor is not defined

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

This is quite strange to me since the MouseCursor class is being used as static.

Mouse.cursor = MouseCursor.BUTTON;

This is what I am using the MouseCursor class as and hence it is static. We got this error posted by a customer and the customer has also attached a screenshot of the error. 
I first assumed that this could be perhaps because he was running an older version of Flash Player ( older than v10 ).

But his screenshot clearly shows that he is running version 10 of the flash player.

Anyone knows why he is getting this error or a way I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can **really** suck sometimes. We had almost this exact issue today but with FunctionReturnWatcher. Try adding this at the top of your class.

```
import flash.ui.MouseCursor;
public class SomeClass {
    private var mc:MouseCursor; // << this seems to trick the compiler
}
```

You may also want to try a clean build too..

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is very odd as the compiler says it's looking in the package flash.ui and can't find MouseCursor. As a wild guess, try updating your SDK at the below link in case you have a bug in your version:

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Downloads

Comment: I am using Flex 4.6 SDK btw :)